# Chrome Extension Button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to execute a script when the extension button is clicked, NOT through 'popup' opening up and then clicking a button in the popup window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked). A popup is optional. The button has an "onClicked" event.

Take a look at [this example](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/) as well. You will notice that the [manifest](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/manifest.json?view=markup) does not have a popup defined. And the [background page](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/background.js?view=markup) listens to the "onClicked" event of the button.

Comment: Thanks, that got me where I needed